# $C_0$-Semigoups - References needed

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, semigroup-of-operators

I'm looking for the references which contains the following theorem with a proof:

**Theorem**

Let $(T_t)$ be a uniformly continuous semigroups with generator $A \in B(H)$, where $H$ is a Hilbert space. Assume that there is a sequence of operators $(A_n)$ in $B(H)$ such that $\|A - A_n \| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.
Then
$$\|T_t - e^{tA_n}\| \to 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty $$
and the converges is uniform in $t$ on every interval $[0, t_0]$, with $t_0 \geq 0$.

I'm not looking for the solution just references, because it is quite an easy exercise.

Thanks for help.

Comment: If it's really an easy exercise, it shouldn't need a reference.

Comment: I need it in my Master's thesis, to save the place it would be better to give the references rather than a proof since it is a well known fact. I can only find a references with a proof of a bit more complicated result when $T_t$ is a $C_0$ semigroup, generated by a closable operator $A$ and $A_n$ is a sequence of bounded operators which converges strongly to $A$ on some dense subset of $H$, then $e^{tA_n}$ converges to $T_t$ strongly on $H$ and the convergence is uniform in $t$.